# How to read text file on base level of java maven project

Tags: java, maven

I want to read a file into a String variable that is located at the base level of my Maven project.

[image]

In this example I'm trying to read the "somerando.sql" file.

I've been trying to use:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/myproj/somerando.sql");
String sql = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
```

but that's not getting it.  Is there a way I can read the file in from here without using it's absolute path on the computer?

Comment: Why don't you place the file in `/src/main/resources` and then read the file from there using `Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("somerando.sql").toURI());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven has some conventions, you should try to follow them. These are helpful.

Besides, after development, the application doesn't live in a Maven project but in a component (Jar/war, etc...). 
So, to avoid absolute path, you should place your files required for application or testing in matching classpath folders.

if your file is for testing, you could move it to the place reserved by Maven to address this need : `yourMavenProject/src/test/resources`

If your file is for the application, you could move it to the place reserved by Maven to address this need : `yourMavenProject/src/main/resources`

Now you can access it with :

```
Path path = Paths.get(YourClass.class.getResource("filter.xml").toURI());
```

Comment: I'm still learning the, "best practices".  This is good information.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Path path = Paths.get("somerando.sql");
String sql = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
```

without the preceding slash. Remember, unless it starts with a slash, the Path API will resolve your path against the JVM's working directory.

It has no knowledge of Eclipse's way of resolving files, where the root (/) might be assumed to be relative to its workspace.

On a side-note, please be careful with creating Strings without specifying the encoding.

Comment: That makes sense however the Files.readAllBytes(path) returns nothing making me think that maybe the path still isn't correct.  Thoughts?

Comment: You can always ask it: `path.toFile().exists()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are not mixing eclipse's project path with the OS path?

Comment: I'm still new to the java/eclipse world.  So, no.  I'm not sure that I'm not mixing it up.